# Bag-in-box packaging

Tags: bottling, pressure, equipment

Is it suitable for beer "bottling" or would the pressure tear it apart? If it's suitable it could be really useful since it can contain a large quantity of liquid with low package weight.

Comment: Are those bags resealable?

Comment: I don't think so, but it would be a cool solution for a party, instead of using a keg or sth.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to [this bag-in-box](http://www.beerinbox.net/), then there's nothing wrong with it.  You basically store flat beer in a box (which is very similar to how soda fountains work), then carbonate it as you serve.  You still, however, have to have a CO2 tank where you're planning to serve it, which is still heavy.  Your use and shelf-life would be similar to a keg.

If you are wanting to actually carbonate beer in and serve it strait out of the bag, I think the pressure would definitely tear it apart.  However if the box was sturdy enough (i.e. not made of cardboard) and smaller than the volume of the bag it could hold up and prevent the bag from popping.  The problem with this setup is once you start drinking the beer begins to go flat, similar to a 2 liter of soda.

**EDIT:**  Have you checked out the [Party Pig](http://www.partypig.com)?  After looking into it a bit, it looks like this is exactly what we've been describing.  It however has a disposable pouch that looks like it sets outside of your beer pouch and produces pressure to prevent your beer from going flat.  I'd be interested to hear from anyone who has used one of those.

Comment: I wanted the second version, I prefer to naturally carbonate my beer. But the problem is that even if the box is small enough, which is most likely true, this prevents the bag from popping, but not from tearing apart and leaking.

Comment: But soda doesn't get carbed as its served.  Its a syrup that gets mixed with carbonated water right?  Regardless, you'd have to put some serious pressure on the flat beer as it comes out of a tap inorder to get it even remotely carbonated if you were going to try and carb "on the fly" as described.

Comment: @brewchez - Yeah, you're right.  When I said "very similar" I meant that you store an uncarbonated product in a bag-in-box and combine it with something else to carbonate it.  Like you said, soda is a little different because it's syrup mixed in with soda water rather than strait CO2.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton - What are you thinking would cause it to tear apart aside from the pressure from CO2 popping it?

Another thing you would need to think about as well is the spout.  That could definitely be a source of failure.

Comment: This Tap-A-Draft system looks like it would be pretty cool to bring to parties:  http://morebeer.com/view_product/18291/102300/Tap-A-Draft_Homebrew_Setup

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring to these cubitainers
http://www.bestcontainers.com/hedpak---cubitainer-cubitainer--combination-packaging-knocked-down-cubitainer---inserts.html
most lhbs carry them in 1 and 5 gallon.  I've used them in the 1 gallon format for a cheap "cask" alternative.  I say cask in the fact that they are carbed to low volumes (around 1.5) and that I do not pour through an engine...i instead dispense with gravity.

they're airtight and the bag collapses as it pours....so minimal oxygen exposure unless your purposefully let it in.